# How to understand the phrase "go to great lengths"?

Tags: phrases

I just learned a phrase "go to great lengths" which means to try one's best. But I've no idea where does this phrase come from, or why it's like this. How to understand "great lengths"? Why using plural form of length? Why "go to great lengths" rather than "go great lengths"?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great lengths are like normal lengths, only greater.

Comment: @Robusto  Why "go to great lengths" rather than "go great lengths"?

Comment: @WeiboLi Probably for the same reason that we don't *go the park*, but rather *go **to** the park*.

Comment: @Anonym Yes, I agree with you, but IMHO "great lengths" is a distance rather than a place. So we should say "go 10 miles" rather than "go to 10 miles", right?

Comment: I disagree that *go to great lengths* means *try one's best*.  Rather it means to expend effort above that which is normally expected.

Comment: You are correct, @Weibo - but this is a "culturalism," that defies strict grammatical analysis.

Comment: @LittleEva Please check Erik Kowal's answer. I thinks his/her explanation makes more sense.

Comment: Let me just take a look to check whether I'm a his/her... Aha!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*To go to* has a non-obvious secondary meaning of 'to perform', 'to undertake' or 'to try very hard' in a few common expressions that have a similar meaning to 'to go to great lengths', such as 'to go to a lot of effort' or 'to go to some trouble'.

Comment: every effort, ends of the earth, nth degree...

Comment: To add to this, I've always thought it was related to distance: if you run very far (great lengths), that's how willing you are to get something done.

Comment: This 'non-obvious secondary meaning' answered my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

*To go to great lengths* is perhaps idiomatic, but easily understandable.  The AHDEL defines length (or [lengths](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=length)) as:

> 7. *often lengths) Extent or degree **to which** an action or policy is carried: went *to great lengths* to prove his point.

Many other dictionaries give this definition as well.

You ask, why not "go great lengths"? It's not a *place* to which someone has gone, it's a *degree to which* someone has gone.

Even if it were a place, it's usually an end point.

"I went all the way to the top to get this assignment for you."

If you want an idiom that is fun to contemplate,

> *to bend over backwards*

means the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I would climb the highest mountain, swim the deepest ocean, ... isn't there a third exemplar?

Comment: @LittleEva - I've heard no mountain too high, no valley too wide, no river too deep... but admittedly that's from a song. ')